# MacBook will not turn on

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, power, startup, motherboard

I have a MacBook pro and it won't turn on. Basically I press the power button and the White light at the front turns on. Then a few seconds later it just crashes and the White light goes off then the laptop turns back on but just seems to be stuck you can hear it and the White light stays on (not flashing like in sleep) and that's it. It just stays like that no screen or keyboard lights, nor the Apple logo. I have tried restarting it and tried holding all the key combinations that the apple site suggest, but still it doesn't work. I've tried it with the power cable plugged in and without. 
It's a 2008 model 15".

I spent ages saving up for the laptop, and if you've eve had a problem with your mac you should know how worrying it is. So any help no matter how big all small would be very welcome. And I'll add a bounty for all my reputation if answers start appearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [problem with the NVIDIA graphics processors](http://support.apple.com/kb/ts2377) that can prevent the MacBook Pro for powering on. I have a 2008 15" MacBook Pro that had symptoms similar to what you are describing about a month ago. I took it to the Genius Bar and they determined that it was the NVIDIA chip causing it and replaced the logic board for free despite the fact that it was not under warranty and I didn't have AppleCare.

My recommendation is to take it in to the Genius Bar and have them check it out. I have found they have great support and have fixed problems out of warranty (such as this one) on more than one occasion. However, it looks like from the comments on another answer that you have done this already. It might be worth a shot trying again and take the support article with you to see if they change the diagnosis.

Or perhaps this answer might help someone else experiencing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Run [Apple Hardware Test](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1509). It sounds to me like a dead hard drive. That's relatively simple to fix. If you have backups, you'll be fine. See what the test says and let us know the results. We can advise over where to go for service / how to go about a DIY repair. If it is the disk (I'm 80% sure), it's quite easy to do yourself (and not too pricey). Exactly the same thing happened to me a year ago.

Comment: I took it to the Apple store the guy there did the same tests as I did from the apple site, and then quoted £410 and 7 days to get it fixed, the logic board is broken apparently, Btw you hardware test requires the laptop to turn, the keyboard,disc drive and screen don't power on. Please tell me there is an alternative to £410. I've built my own PC so I know what's what inside a computer.

Comment: Doing it yourself wouldn't really save much money; the part is pricey at £416. (http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Repair/Installing-MacBook-Pro-13-Inch-Unibody-Mid-2010-Logic-Board-Replacement/4314/1). You can try other Mac repair shops, but I doubt you'll get a much better price.

Comment: How can it be so expensive, they must make these things in huge quantities, what makes it so expensive compared to say a windows based laptop?

Comment: That's Apple for you. Not much anyone can do about it. For the future, I do recommend their extended warranties.

Comment: Yes, we all know to what our wallet is exposed to when choosing Apple's products! :)
As said above, I recommend taking an Apple Care (which I didn't do and now regret... ;)
For your issue, as Nathan said, you probably won't have better price elsewhere due to the hardware part's price.

Comment: But surely I can't just take out Apple Care? Otherwise when I had the problem, I'd buy AppleCare and then just get the fix free (only for the much less cost of AppleCare).

Comment: You have to buy AppleCare within the first year before the standard warranty expires, so it is too late for this machine. I generally get AppleCare when it is a new model/design/product. In my experience, stable products tend to have fewer issues. And Apple often repairs known issues, such as the NVIDIA graphics chip problem, for free despite being outside of warranty coverage.